# How can I deploy my Catalyst application as a debian package (or suitable alternative)?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, debian, packaging, catalyst

After testing my [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst) application and deciding to deploy it I would like to package it up so I can easily pull it in on the staging and live servers, manage dependencies and easily roll-back via the flexibility of package versioning. As my production OS is Ubuntu I figured packaging it as a deb package would make most sense.

I am predicting I will have to create a second package of all my perl module dependencies as many are not provided by my distribution, or package them independently - though that may be a lot of work.

Does anyone have any experience of doing this - or a sane, similar alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build your own Debian packages out of CPAN packages:

- Install Debian helper scripts

  `sudo apt-get install dh-make-perl`
- Download `MODULE` from CPAN and build Debian package

  `cpan2deb MODULE`

Answer (score 4):

[dh-make-perl](http://packages.debian.org/dh-make-perl) is actually the right tool to put CPAN modules into Debian packages. Together with apt-file it can even prepare proper dependencies for you.

About being able to "easily roll-back" though requires special attention to versioning or workflows. There are several approaches that might get your job done here:

- If you can force-downgrade packages you have won already most of the time unless you have very specific maintainer scripts that do jobs on package upgrades - then you will have to make them able to handle the downgrade, too
- If you have to go the regular upgrade-path, using approaches like using "< newversion>+rollback< oldversion>" or similar might be something to consider.

Dependency-packages are always a good idea for deployments to make sure no required package actually is missing. Also, you might want to invest some time in management frameworks like [puppet](http://packages.debian.org/puppet), they might come handy here, too.